# Auto generate 2 dimensional Array,

Tags: java, arrays

Currently I have a 2D array, with values of 1 or 0. I hard coded 0 and 1's in their position in the array as i need them in this sequences.

```
  //{ { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },N
  //    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },S
 //  { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, W
//  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 } };E
```

Is there a better solution to do this instead of placing each value of the array exactly like in the example above. As if i had to do this for 100 X 100 array it would be take several days

Comment: thats easy to implement. give yourself a try. good luck

Comment: What is the rule that defines how an array should look? I don't see any particular system in how your arrays are formed.

Comment: Agree with @Suseika - Is there any logic to the arrays or are they just random 0's and 1's?

Comment: @Suseika: Check out my explanation in my answer.

Comment: @DugD: Please see my answer for the correct approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you want like this

```
count=0;
for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=25;j++)
    {
       if(i==0)
       {
            if(j>5)
                a[i][j]=0;
            else    
                a[i][j]=1;
       }
       else if(i==1)
       {
            if(j<19)
                a[i][j]=0;
            else    
                a[i][j]=1;
       }
       else if(i==2)
       {
            if(count==0)
            {
                a[i][j]=0;
            }   
            else    
                a[i][j]=1;
        if(count==4) 
           count=0;
         else  
           count=count+1;
       }
       else if(i==3)
       {
            if(count==4)
            {
                a[i][j]=0;
            }   
            else    
                a[i][j]=1;
        if(count==4) 
           count=0;
         else  
           count=count+1;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't just post code, describe what it does and how it does so.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will create your desired data structure when provided. This is a highly efficient solution.

We know that the first (1<sup>st</sup>) dimension will always be four, since North, South, West, and East are the only directions. The second (2<sup>nd</sup>) dimension will be calculated as the square of `n`.

After we have established the dimensions of the matrix and initialized it, we can begin to iterated over the range of `0` to the square of `n`.

### Code

```java
public int[][] generateDirectionalMatrix(int n) {
    int sq = Math.pow(n, 2);               // 2nd Dimension
    int[][] matrix = new int[4][sq];
    int top = n;                           // Top
    int rgt = n - 1;                       // Right
    int bot = sq - rgt;                    // Bottom
    int lft = 0;                           // Left

    for (int idx = 0; idx < sq; idx++) {
        int col = idx % n;                 // Column

        matrix[0][i] = idx <  top ? 0 : 1; // North
        matrix[1][i] = idx >  bot ? 0 : 1; // South
        matrix[2][i] = col == lft ? 0 : 1; // West
        matrix[3][i] = col == rgt ? 0 : 1; // East
    }

    return matrix;
}

generateDirectionalMatrix(100) // Generates 4 x 10,000 (100 x 100) matrix.
```

### Output

This is the output of a matrix where `n = 5`, as provided in your question.

```java
{ // Structure: 4 x 25 (5 x 5)
  { // North
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1
  }, { // South
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0
  }, { // West
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1
  }, { // East
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0
  }
};
```

### Example

I ported the code above to JavaScript for a live demo.

The following code creates a 4 x 64 (8 x 8) matrix.

```js
var dir = 'North,South,West,East'.split(',');

var n = 8;
var sq = Math.pow(n, 2);
var matrix = [[], [], [], []];

for (var i = 0; i < sq; i++) {
  matrix[0].push(i < n ? 0 : 1);         // North
  matrix[1].push(i >= sq-n ? 0 : 1);     // South
  matrix[2].push(i % n === 0 ? 0 : 1);   // West
  matrix[3].push(i % n === n-1 ? 0 : 1); // East
}

// Display
for (var row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className += ' dir';
  div.innerHTML = dir[row] + '\n' + Array(n*2).join('-') + '\n';
  for (var col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
    div.innerHTML += matrix[row][col] + (col % n === n-1 ? '\n' : ' ');
  }
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
.dir {
  float: left;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: #E7E7E7;
  border: thin solid black;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```